# divide classes into sub functions/classes python

Tags: python

First time poster and python newbie here, this question is probably asked before, but I am not able to find any answer.

I have a Class that reads robot status data, this works fine and I am able to dive my data into methods that are working fine when i call them. But I would like to divide my class even more, so the data is structured better. for example

I have some methods the reads and return target_data

```
def target_joint_positions(self):
    t_j_p = self.read_data()[1:7]
    return t_j_p

def target_joint_velocities(self):
    t_j_v = self.read_data()[7:13]
    return t_j_v

def target_joint_currents(self):
    t_j_c = self.read_data()[19:25]
    return t_j_c
```

And similar methods returning actual_data:

```
def actual_joint_positions(self):
    a_j_p = self.read_data()[31:37]
    return a_j_p

def actual_joint_velocities(self):
    a_j_v = self.read_data()[37:43]
    return a_j_v

def actual_joint_currents(self):
    a_j_c = self.read_data()[43:49]
    return a_j_c
```

So what I would like to accomplish is that when i make a instance of my class, instead of getting all the methods i would like something like this:

inst = Class_Name()

inst.target. (list of target methods)

inst.actual. (list of actual methods)

I have looked into nested classes and inheritance but I have not been successful in achieving my goal. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: It sounds like this is a namespace management issue, where you could like to encapsulate all of the "target" methods under `target` and the "actual" methods under `actual`.  The only way I can think of to do this is to create class instances for both  `target` and `actual`, initializing them with `inst` so they know what the effective `self` should be when their methods are invoked.  I don't like it though.  It adds complexity and runtime cost for very little gain.  Prefixing the method names, as in your example, should give you most of the benefit with none of the added cost.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see a list of `target` methods pop up in your IDE?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, @quamrana, yes I would like to see it in the IDE, and also be able to call the method. I am making this for some students to use, and I would like to better explain the class and where within the class they can find different types of data. My main class now have about 50 methods, so I would just like to divide the into sub methods(if thats a word in python:-))

Comment: Surely you can already see the list of all methods when you type `inst.` and then just the target methods when you type `inst.t`

Comment: Thanks @Tom Karzes, so from you comment i take it that maybe it`s best to just leave it as is?

Comment: @espeno A better approach might be to combine, for instance, several of the `target` methods into a single method with an additional parameter which indicates what you want to extract, e.g. `inst.target_joint(self, field)` where `field` is one of `"positions"`, `"velocities"`, or `"currents"`.  But if you really want them to be separate methods, then I'd just leave it.

Comment: yes, no problem with the inst.t @quamrana, just wondering if it was an easy way to divide it further. Or if this is even recommend/standard practice in python?

Comment: Your highest priority should be semantics: Should your class have both `actual` and `target` methods, or should there be two classes, one with `actual` and one with `target`? Notice in [https://wiki.c2.com/?XpSimplicityRules](Simple Design) that `Expresses every Idea` is above `No Superfluous parts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

You can do the following:

```py
class TargetMetrics:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def joint_positions(self):
        return self.data[1:7]
    ...

class ActualMetrics:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def joint_positions(self):
        return self.data[31:37]
    ...

class RobotMetrics:
    def __init__(self):
        data = read_data()
        self.actual = ActualMetrics(data)
        self.target = TargetMetrics(data)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem now is that the method read_data() is only called when i initialize the RobotMetrics class, i need this to be called every time i call the joint_positions method. Are there a way to call the method read_data() from the ActualMetrics Class? I whould still like the method to be within the RobotMetrics class. So I think what I would like to do is just inherit the read_data() method from from RobotMetrics, not the whole class, is there a way to do this?